# Nginxで特定のパス以下へのアクセスに対し、全て同じディレクトリのファイルを返したい

Tags: nginx

よろしくお願いいたします.

以下の様な構造が可能か調べております.
お知恵がございましたら, ご教示頂ければ幸甚に存じます.

- 以下URLへのアクセスを仮定 (以下, 接頭はhttp://としてお読み下さい)
  example.com/v1/index.html
  example.com/v1/aa/index.html
  example.com/v1/aa/bb/index.html
  example.com/v1/ab/index.html
  example.com/v1/ac/index.html
- 上記URLへのアクセス(v1配下への全アクセス)の場合, 以下の様に /var/www/直下のindex.htmlを返したい.
  /var/www/index.html
- *.css, *.jpgの場合においても, /var/www/直下のfileを返したい
  /var/www/*.jpg
  /var/www/*.css

このような設定は, nginxで可能でしょうか?
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします.

Answer (score 1):

自己解決致しました.
ありがとうございました.

```
location ~ /tier1/(.*)/(.*) {
    alias    /usr/share/nginx/html/$2;
    break;
}

location ~ /tier1/(.*) {
    alias    /usr/share/nginx/html/$1;
    break;
}
```